# Producing LaTex tables from OpenOffice Calc

Tags: tables, automation, open-office

Calc2latex is a great add-on for OpenOffice Calc, but no longer works since about version 4.? of Calc. I am now working with Calc 5.0.3

Is anyone aware of a way to automate production of latex tables/tabular environments from a calc spreadsheet?

Comment: Would exporting the table as a `.csv` file, and importing this `.csv` file in LaTeX be an option?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the package [`odsfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/odsfile), it requires `lualatex` to work.